# How do I collect all external links in Sphinx?

Tags: python-sphinx

I have to put some external links in a manual, and want to have, at the end (of section or even the whole book, not important), a list of all links, without repeating them manually. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an excerpt from a doc with bibliography (the rendered version is [here](http://packages.python.org/pyteomics/api/achrom.html)):

```
Several attempts were made in order to improve the accuracy of prediction by
the additive model (for a review of the field we suggest to read [#Baczek]_
and [#Babushok]_). The two implemented in this module are the logarithmic
length correction term described in [#MantLogLen]_ and additional sets of
retention coefficients for terminal amino acid residues [#Tripet]_.
<...>


References
----------
<...>
.. [#Babushok] Babushok, V. I.; Zenkevich, I. G. `Retention Characteristics of
   Peptides in RP-LC: Peptide Retention Prediction.
   <http://dx.doi.org/10.1365/s10337-010-1721-8>`_
   Chromatographia, 2010, 72 (9-10), 781-797.
<...>

.. [#Tripet] Tripet, B.; Cepeniene, D.; Kovacs, J. M.; Mant, C. T.; Krokhin,
   O. V.; Hodges, R. S. `Requirements for prediction of peptide retention time
   in reversed-phase high-performance liquid chromatography:
   hydrophilicity/hydrophobicity of side-chains at the N- and C-termini of
   peptides are dramatically affected by the end-groups and location.
   <http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.chroma.2006.12.024>`_
   Journal of chromatography A, 2007, 1141 (2), 212-25.
```