# Can I keep all my external links in a separate file with Sphinx?

Tags: hyperlink, python-sphinx

I have a Sphinx project with a collection of files that contain external links as references at the bottom of each file like this:

```
Some text with `my link`_, more text
100 lines of text ...

.. _my link: http://example.com
```

I'd like to reorganize my files, splitting them, merging them and reusing external links. To make this easier, I'd like to keep my links in a separate file, each one with a unique id that I can reference in the text. Is there a way to do this? The rendered output should still create an external link, not a footnote like it was suggested in [How do I collect all external links in Sphinx?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12106924/130121)

Comment: Would replacements in an `rst_epilog` do what you want? https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/basics.html#substitutions

Comment: Thank you, @StevePiercy, that put me on the right track! I don't even need replacement (because I want my links texts to be flexible), I can just include all the link references at the bottom of each file.

Answer (score 6):

This can be solved with the right settings in `conf.py`:

```py
# Exclude link file
exclude_patterns = ['_build', 'links.rst']

# make rst_epilog a variable, so you can add other epilog parts to it
rst_epilog =""
# Read link all targets from file
with open('links.rst') as f:
     rst_epilog += f.read()
```

`links.rst` looks like this:

```
.. _my link: http://example.com
.. _my other link: http://example2.com
```

With this setup, I'm flexible to use either the unique ID as the link label or provide a custom link label:

```
Some text with `my link`_ and a `custom label<my other link>`_
```

Comment: The usefulness of this is keeping all the hard coded external URLs centralized in 1 external file? So allowing to import in conf.py and then using those ID across your project `.rst`s?!

Comment: @bad_coder Exactly. There are some external articles that I want to link frequently from different pages, my text being a non-linear medium where people can start at any "page" of the document. It's just the programmer in me that doesn't want to repeat himself.

Comment: Really useful - simplifies management of project URLs that can change. An ideal solution would support URL injection at runtime (e.g. handlebars/mustache) but this is an excellent managed-solution.